# in Microsoft ML how does one configure a score and predict label output

Tags: c#, ml.net

We are evaluating ML.Net, release 0.6, I get frustrated with the error messages...
My issue, perhaps some one know what I am doing wrong.

I have a class that we created for ML.Net, it has features and a label.
in the learning Pipeline I add

```
var pipeline = new LearningPipeline() {
    new TextLoader(_trainingFile.FullName).CreateFrom<MyClass>(useHeader: true, separator: separator),
    new ColumnCopier(("Trend", "Label")),
    new Dictionarizer("Label"),
    new CategoricalOneHotVectorizer("Trend"),
    new ColumnConcatenator("Features,"col1","col2",... "Trend"),
    new StochasticDualCoordinateAscentClassifier()
    {
        Shuffle = false,
    },
    new PredictedLabelColumnOriginalValueConverter()
    {
            PredictedLabelColumn="PredictedLabel"
    }
};
```

My Predict class looks like this:

```
class MyPrediction
{
    [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
    public string PredictedLabels;

    [ColumnName("Score")]
    public float Scores;
}
```

The Trend column is a string with Enum labels. I run the training and it works well, not always predicting correct but when I add the score column I get an error.

*Can't bind the IDataView column 'Score' of type 'Vec' to field or property 'Scores' of type 'System.Single'.*

What do I need to do to get the predicted value and the score, anny suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Maybe make the `Scores` field an array of float - `float[]`?

Comment: Hi Jon, okey that seems to do the trick, looks like I get an output for each field in my model and not a score for just the label

Answer (score 1):

To answer more broadly, any ML.NET trained model is an `ITransformer`. This means that it can `Transform()` an incoming dataset (the 'examples') into the output dataset (the 'predictions').

This capability can be referred to as 'batch prediction': once you have a whole dataset of examples, you can run the model on them all with one call to `Transform()`.

In order to facilitate a 'example to example' prediction, we have added the `PredictionFunction` idiom. [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/MlNetCookBook.md#how-do-i-use-the-model-to-make-one-prediction) is a complete example.

You can 'request' any number of columns from the result of prediction: just add the corresponding fields to your 'prediction' class, and the `PredictionFunction` will populate them appropriately.

Comment: Hi Zruty, How do I deal with several output columns, as well as how does one deal with multiple enums in the input , does one combine all in an array in CategoricalOneHotVectorizer or a new CategoricalOneHotVectorizer for each?

Comment: For several output columns, just declare several fields in your output class. As for multiple categorical features, each of the approaches you listed is viable

Comment: The class for the predictions contains enums, in the csv used to train I have r.FieldName.OneHotEncoding(), how does one enter this ? as string? as Enum? or cast them to an int in the training as well as in the prediction?

Comment: Now I get  "Training set has 0 instances, aborting training.", where does this come from?

Comment: Something is not configured correctly. It's impossible to tell more without actual code and a snippet of data.